# Redis takes a lot of time at a particular time every hour

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis

I am running a redis cluster with 6 nodes, 1 master/node and 1 slave/master. Dataset is around 60-80GB/node. We are experiencing a peculiar problem where **every 16th minute of each hour**, redis responds very slow. Usual response time is < **5ms**, but at 16th minute, the avg response time shoots above **15s**. **Is there any background process in redis that runs hourly?**

My redis.conf is as below:-

```
port 23000

cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 20000
cluster-slave-validity-factor 1

logfile redis.log
loglevel notice
slowlog-log-slower-than 1000
slowlog-max-len 64
latency-monitor-threshold 100
maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl
slave-read-only no
protected-mode no
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /data/redis/redis-master
appendonly yes
appendfilename redis-staging-ao.aof
```

Comment: Do you have any cron job that calls some slow command, e.g. `KEYS`, every hour?

Comment: @for_stack, there is none. I searched but could not found anything of that sort. Is there a way to check that? Or if we can see that what exactly is happening with Redis during that time?

Comment: Maybe you can try the `SLOWLOG` command to find some clue. Also check if there's other processes on the machine highly consuming CPU or network IO.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and at the exact same time (every 16th minute). But it just turns out we had a cronjob that was using REDIS keys command hourly to clear some cache